# How to define byte? null parameter

Tags: .net, nullable

How to create null byte?

This is what I do

```
byte? nb = null;

methodCall (rdr.IsDBNull(15) ? nb : rdr.GetByte(15));
```

This does not even complile.
What is the proper syntax?

```
methodCall (rdr.IsDBNull(15) ? (null)byte : rdr.GetByte(15));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
(byte?)null : rdr.GetByte(...)
```

Comment: Cannot accept for 7 minutes.  Now that I see the answer it makes sense.